Solve SDE $dX_t = X_tW_tdt + dW_t,$
I was working on question 7.5d in Applied Stochastic Analysis by  by Eric Vanden-Eijnden, Tiejun Li, and Weinan E, which is given as
$$dX_t =  X_tW_tdt + dW_t, X_{t|t=0} = X_0, t\in \mathbb{R}_+$$
Where Wt is standard Wiener Process.
I tried to let $Y_t=e^{−tW_t}X_t$ and looked at $dY_t$ trying to get rid of $W_t$. However it's introducing the quadratic covariation term which makes the whole thing more chaotic, and $W_t$ still exists in the exponential form.
I'm not sure how to handle the $W_t$ term before dt. Any hint would be appreciated! Many thanks in advance!

What have you tried?

@JoseAvilez I tried to let $Y_t = e^{-tW_t}X_t$ and looked at $dY_t$ trying to get rid of $W_t$. However it's introducing the quadratic covariation term which makes the whole thing more chaotic, and $W_t$ still exists in the exponential form.

Please edit your question with your attempt

@JoseAvilez Thanks for your reminder!

It will be better to take $Y_t:=\exp\left(-\int_0^t W_s,ds\right)X_t$ as a starting point.

To solve problems like these, rather than trying to guess the correct process to introduce, it may be easier to just let $Y_t := e^{Z_t}X_t$ where $dZ_t = \alpha_t dt  + \beta_t dW_t$ for some processes $\alpha,\beta$ to be determined later.  We compute
\begin{align*}
dY_t &= e^{Z_t}X_t dZ_t + e^{Z_t} dX_t + \frac 12 e^{Z_t} X_t d\langle Z,Z\rangle_t + e^{Z_t} d\langle X,Z\rangle_t \\
&= e^{Z_t}\big( X_t (\alpha_t dt + \beta_t dW_t) + X_t W_t dt + dW_t + \frac 12 X_t \beta_t^2 dt + \beta_t dt\big) \\
&= e^{Z_t} \big( (X_t \alpha_t  + X_tW_t + \frac 12 X_t \beta_t^2 + \beta_t)dt + (X_t \beta_t + 1)dW_t \big).
\end{align*}
Our goal is to make it so that $X_t$ doesn't appear on the left-hand side, which can be done by choosing $\alpha_t = -W_t$ and $\beta_t = 0$, so $Z_t = -\int_0^t W_s ds$.  Then the above simplifies to
\begin{align*}
dY_t &= e^{Z_t} dW_t,
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
e^{Z_t} X_t &= Y_0 + \int_0^t e^{Z_s} dW_s.
\end{align*}
Now, solving for $X$ and using that $X_0 = Y_0$ gives $$X_t = e^{-Z_t}X_0 + \int_0^t e^{Z_s-Z_t}dW_s.$$
